# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 when compiled

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture, i386

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_end_ctors", referenced from:
      _callConstructors in kernel.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
  "_start_ctors", referenced from:
      _callConstructors in kernel.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I keep getting this error when ever I try to compile my scripts as mykernel.iso file

makefile:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
ASPARAMS = -m32
 
objects = kernel.o loader.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $< -o $@ $(objects)

install:mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp $< iso/boot/
    echo 'set timeout=0' > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry My OS' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  boot' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

kernel.cpp:

```
void print(char* str){
    unsigned short* VoiceMemory = (unsigned short*) 0xb8000;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '/0'; i++){
        VoiceMemory[i] = (VoiceMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
    }
}

typedef void (*constructor)();
extern "C" constructor start_ctors;
extern "C" constructor end_ctors;
extern "C" void callConstructors(){
    for(constructor* i  = &start_ctors; i != &end_ctors; i++){
        (*i)();
    }
}

extern "C" void kernelMain(const void* multiboot_structure, unsigned int /*multiboot_magic*/){
    print("Hello world in OS!");

    while(true);
}
```

loader.s:

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM
 
.section .text
.extern _kernelMain
.extern callConstructors;
.global loader

loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain

_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop

.section .bss
.space 2*1024*1024
kernel_stack:
```

I am on MacOS

Comment: Where do you define `_start_ctors` and `_end_ctors`?

Comment: Oh I forgot, that may be the reason

Comment: About the missing `main` function, it might be that you need to specify some special flags for `ld` to not look for it?